# SQL Sending values where code matches another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis-2012

I have a table with data records:

#### T1:

Example T1 Data:

```
Unique_id   RatingA   RatingB   RatingC
    123       1          3       Null
    456      -1        Null       2
```

I have another table with a code that equates to the ratings,

#### T2:

```
 Rating_Name  Rating_Code
   RatingA        11
   RatingB        21
   RatingC        31
```

I need to send the `Unique_id` from `T1`, rating codes from `T2` with the Rating values from `T1`.

#### Desired output

My export file should look like this, taking the *Rating* from the corresponding column (A, B or C):

```
Unique_id  Rating_Code  Rating
   123           11        1
   123           21        3
   123           31      (null)
   456           11       -1
   456           21      (null)
   456           31        2
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You want to pivot T2 then join them.

Comment: Will there only ever be three Ratings (A, B, C)? Or can further ratings (D, E, etc.) be added over time?

Comment: There are hundreds of ratings, I was simplifying my example.

Comment: Yes, T1 has over 200 rating### columns.

Answer (score 2):

You could you a `CASE WHEN` clause to unpivot the three columns for **RatingA, B** and **C**:

```sql
SELECT      T1.Unique_id,
            T2.Rating_Code,
            CASE Rating_Name
                WHEN 'RatingA' THEN T1.RatingA
                WHEN 'RatingB' THEN T1.RatingB
                WHEN 'RatingC' THEN T1.RatingC
            END AS Rating
FROM        T1
CROSS JOIN  T2
```

Output:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------+
| Unique_id | Rating_Code | Rating |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
|    123    |       11    |    1   |
|    123    |       21    |    3   |
|    123    |       31    | (null) |
|    456    |       11    |   -1   |
|    456    |       21    | (null) |
|    456    |       31    |    2   |
+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dd288/1).

If you have other records in **T2** than the three given in your question, then add a `WHERE` clause at the end of the statement:

```sql
WHERE       Rating_Name IN ('RatingA', 'RatingB', 'RatingC');
```

## Addendum

As you have indicated you have in fact many (hundreds) of such RatingXXX columns, it must be said that this is a bad database design. In fact, the output you want to generate should be a proper table that you would keep updated instead of these columns.

Anyway, to help you produce the above SQL without having to type those hundreds of column names, you could use this:

```sql
SELECT      concat('WHEN ''', Rating_Name, ''' THEN T1.', Rating_Name)
FROM        T2
```

This would output something like:

```
WHEN 'RatingA' THEN T1.RatingA
WHEN 'RatingB' THEN T1.RatingB
WHEN 'RatingC' THEN T1.RatingC
```

... which you can copy into your final SQL's `CASE` clause. This assumes of course that the rating name in your table **T2** is the exact column name in **T1**.

Comment: That worked beautifully. Although there are hundreds of records. Any statements that may select them into the CASE statement vs manually typing them all? @trincot, thanks so much for reformatting my original post. It's my first time using stack overflow & I appreciate the help!

Comment: Glad you like it. Are you saying your T1 table has hundreds of RatingXXX columns?

Comment: Yes T1 has over a hundred rating### columns.

Comment: I added a paragraph about that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Unique_id, Rating_Code, Rating
from
    T1 cross apply
    (values
        ('RatingA', RatingA),
        ('RatingB', RatingB),
        ('RatingC', RatingC)
    ) pvt(Rating_Name, Rating)
    inner join T2
        on T2.Rating_Name = pvt.Rating_Name
```

This is very similar to @trincot's answer. One small different is that I make *no* assumption that you want all the values from `T2`. It's not clear whether that's correct now or might be incorrect in the future. In @trincot's favor it's possible, though not likely, that you don't have `cross apply` available on your version of SQL Server.